# EOF on Pipe is printing garbage

Tags: c, operating-system, pipe, eof

**Edit:** So with some additional debugging, EOF is successfully getting written to the pipe (I know this because I tested to make sure that the `write()` function was returning 0 on `produceStdin`. **HOWEVER** when **reading** from the same pipe, it says i've encountered EOF (good) but the value of the EOF element is equal to 255 (instead of -1 like it typically is). Does anyone know why this is the case???

I'm trying to write this program but when I encounter EOF from stdin it's not writing a -1 to the pipe. For whatever reason when trying to pass along the EOF via the pipes garbage is being written and thus all subsequent processes are being caught in an infinite loop.

All those print statement other than the one printing the array in the `printOut()` function are me trying to debug it (can't use the debugger because of the forks)

Also: Some of those comments are recycled so if you see mention of a "buffer" it's because 
this was previously programmed using buffers instead of pipes.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX_CHARS 81 //80 chars + null-terminator
#define NUM_CHILDREN 3

void produceStdin(int writePipe);
void child1(int readPipe, int writePipe);
void child2(int readPipe, int writePipe);
void printOut(int readPipe);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int i,pipe1[2],pipe2[2],pipe3[2];
    pid_t childPid;

    if(pipe(pipe1)==-1||pipe(pipe2)==-1||pipe(pipe3)==-1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error in creating pipe");
    }
    //despite what it looks like only four children are being forked,
    // all to the same parent. The children get called to their respective 
    //functions where they get terminated before getting to fork themselves.
    for(i=0;i<NUM_CHILDREN;i++)
    {
        childPid=fork();
        switch (childPid) {
            case -1:
                perror("fork() failed. Aborting.");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

            case 0:
                switch (i) {
                    case 0:
                        close(pipe1[0]); //close pipe1 read (since we're reading from stdin)

                        close(pipe2[0]); //close pipe2
                        close(pipe2[1]);

                        printf("right before calling stdin i=%d\n",i);
                        produceStdin(pipe1[1]); //write to pipe1
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        close(pipe1[1]); //close pipe1 write

                        close(pipe2[0]); //close pipe2 read

                        close(pipe3[0]); //close pipe3
                        close(pipe3[1]);
                        printf("right before calling child1 i=%d\n",i);
                        child1(pipe1[0], pipe2[1]); //read from pipe1, write to pipe2
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        close(pipe1[0]); //close pipe1
                        close(pipe1[1]);

                        close(pipe2[1]); //close pipe2 write

                        close(pipe3[0]); //close pipe3 read
                        printf("right before calling child2 i=%d\n",i);
                        child2(pipe2[0], pipe3[1]); //read from pipe2, write to pipe3
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }

            default:
                if(i==2)
                {
                    close(pipe1[1]); //close pipe1
                    close(pipe1[0]);

                    close(pipe2[1]); //close pipe2
                    close(pipe2[0]);

                    close(pipe3[1]); //close pipe3 write

                    printOut(pipe3[0]); //read from pipe3 read
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
void produceStdin(int writePipe)
{
    int c=0;
    while(c!=EOF)
    {
        c=fgetc(stdin);
        write(writePipe, &c, sizeof(char)); //writing EOF here is where the problem starts I believe
    }
    printf("Got EOF in ProdStdin\n");
    printf("EOF has a value of: %d",c);
    exit(0);
}
void child1(int readPipe, int writePipe)
{
    int c=0;
    while(c!=EOF)
    {
        read(readPipe,&c,sizeof(char));
//        printf("Child1 got a char from pipe1: %c\n",c);
        if(c=='\n')
        {
            c=' '; //test for newline
        }
        write(writePipe, &c, sizeof(char));
    }
    exit(0);
}
void child2(int readPipe, int writePipe)
{
    int c=0;
    int c2=0;
    while(c!=EOF && c2!=EOF)
    {
        read(readPipe, &c, sizeof(char));
//        printf("Child2 got a char from pipe2: %c\n",c);
        if(c=='*')
        {
            read(readPipe, &c2, sizeof(char)); //if c is a * remove another char
            if(c2=='*')
            {
                c='^'; //if c2 is a * then put a ^ on buffer3
                write(writePipe,&c,sizeof(char));
            }
            else
            {
                write(writePipe,&c,sizeof(char));
                write(writePipe,&c2,sizeof(char));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            write(writePipe,&c,sizeof(char));
        }
    }
    exit(0);
}
void printOut(int readPipe)
{
    int c=0,numChars=0;
    char output[MAX_CHARS];
    while (c!=EOF)
    {
        read(readPipe, &c, sizeof(char));
//        printf("PrintOut got a char from pipe3: %c\nnumChars= %d\n",c,numChars);
        if (numChars==MAX_CHARS-2)
        {
            printf("%s\n",output);
            memset(output, '\0', sizeof(char)*MAX_CHARS);
            numChars=0;
        }

        output[numChars]=c;
        numChars++;
    }
    printf("ABOUT TO EXIT PRINTOUT()\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Alternative**  Pass a 2 byte version of what was read through the pipe, so the receiving end can distinguish between a char and EOF.

```
int c = 0;
while(c!=EOF) {
  c = fgetc(stdin);
  short sc = (short) c;
  // `sc` will _typically_ have the values -1 (EOF) and 0,1,2,... 255.
  write(writePipe, &sc, sizeof(sc));
}

int c=0;
int c2=0;
while(c != EOF && c2 != EOF) {
  short sc;          
  if (sizeof(sc) != read(readPipe, &sc, sizeof(sc))) handle_error();
  // `sc` will _typically_ have the values -1 (EOF) and 0,1,2,... 255.
  c = sc;
  ...
```

---

**Original** suggested answer.

`c` does not become EOF until *after* all the characters are read.
Use:

```
// while(c!=EOF) {
//   c=fgetc(stdin);
//   write(writePipe, &c, sizeof(char));
// }
while((c = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF) {
  write(writePipe, &c, sizeof(char));
}
```

The return value of `read(readPipe, &c, sizeof(char));` should be assessed instead of looking for `c` becoming EOF.  EOF does not fit in a `char`.

```
// int c=0;
// int c2=0;
// while(c!=EOF && c2!=EOF) {
//    read(readPipe, &c, sizeof(char));

char c=0;
char c2=0;
while(1 == read(readPipe, &c, sizeof(char))) {
```

---

Comment: Can you perhaps clarify? The way my loop is written, EOF is written to the pipe before exiting. Regardless of whether the char read is EOF or not I want to write it to the pipe before exiting, thus my loop is `while(c!=EOF)` instead of `while((c=fgetc(stdin))!=EOF)`

Comment: In other words, EOF is successfully being read and then written to the pipe, it may be useful to read the edit I added to the top of my post

Comment: Ok, so I could reformat the loops based solely on the read. Say, for the sake of being stubborn, that I **did** want to write `EOF` to the pipe and then read it, can one do that? Also, if i recall correctly `EOF=-1` which should fit in one byte should it not, I ask this because I specifically make my `c,c2` `int` type instead of `char` to accommodate the EOF case?

Comment: @sreya "EOF is written to the pipe before exiting".  This is not true as by only passing 1 byte, you have loss the difference between EOF and a char, like `\377`.

Comment: @sreya, fgetc() returns 256 positive + 1 negative different values.  To pass that information through the pipe, one should use > 1 byte per write.  Alternative posted writes 2.  EOF is _always_ < 0. It is often -1, but not specified to be so.

Comment: @sreya You "EOF" got through before because of `write(writePipe, &c, sizeof(char)); read(readPipe, &c2, sizeof(char))`.  If `c` was 255 or -1, they have the same 8 least significant bytes.  That is all you are piping with `sizeof(char)`.  Upon reading into `c2`, you do not know if the original `char` that was read from fgetc() had a bit pattern of 0b11111111 or was an EOF.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39301/discussion-between-chux-and-sreya)

Answer (score 0):

This bit is problematic in the writing code:

```
int c = 0;

while(c!=EOF)
{
    c=fgetc(stdin);
    write(writePipe, &c, sizeof(char));
}
```

You should be using:

```
int c;

while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF)
{
    char c1 = c;
    write(writePipe, &c1, sizeof(char));
}
```

The output from `fgetc()` is either an unsigned character value returned as an `int` or EOF.  As it was, you detected EOF and then wrote a byte to the pipe that really shouldn't be written.  The use of `c1` is necessary in general; you probably get away with what you wrote on a little-endian machine, but it will not work properly on a big-endian machine.  You should probably check that the write succeeds, too.

The equivalent reading code has similar problems.  You have:

```
int c=0;
while(c!=EOF)
{
    read(readPipe,&c,sizeof(char));
    if(c=='\n')
    {
        c=' '; //test for newline
    }
    write(writePipe, &c, sizeof(char));
}
```

You need:

```
char c;
while (read(readPipe, &c, sizeof(char)) == sizeof(char))
{
    if (c == '\n')
        c = ' ';
    write(writePipe, &c, sizeof(char));
}
```

Again, there were the little-endian vs big-endian portability issue, and the testing of the input operation (always, but *always* check the input operation; you can often get away without checking the output, but you must always check the input).

Note that single character I/O via `read()` and `write()` is expensive for high-performance applications.  Standard I/O single-character I/O is OK because it buffers the input or output and doesn't invoke the overhead of a system call per read and per write.  For toy applications, you won't notice the overhead.

This may well be what [chux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2410359/chux) said in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19389875/15168), expressed in a slightly different way.

Comment: Yeah this was a conceptual exercise not a performance one but thanks for the input. How does one pass a message via pipes to let each process know that the input stream has hit EOF if you can't actually pass EOF? Just pass a custom variable or something?

Comment: Like, I just closed the pipe after I was done writing and that seems to have done the job

Comment: Yup; closing the pipe lets the other end know that there is no more data -- as long as there was only one process with the write end of the pipe open.  It is important therefore to make sure that unused pipe descriptors are closed in all the processes in a set.  That's often a lot of closes.  Think of 'plumbing' as "stopping leakage (of file descriptors) by closing all the pipes that aren't needed".